# PowerShell Loop to run a command against using file

Tags: shell, powershell, for-loop

I am using below code in shell. I need to run the same in PowerShell.
I have frame list in file and I need to excute the command in loop and I need append the prefix variable to each output

```
for g in `cat /home/capacity-report/vmax3-frame.txt`
do
    echo $g; `symsg -sid $g list -v` > /home/capacity-report/sg
done
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for Input and Output file to see what is going on.

Comment: What environment is this intended for? Windows/Linux/MacOs? Maybe the tag powershell-core is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell code for that shell snippet is pretty similar to the original:

```
foreach ($g in cat 'C:\path\to\input.txt') {
    echo $g; Invoke-Expression "$(symsg -sid $g list -v)" > 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
}
```

And the next time please try doing this yourself first. SO is not a free translation service. I'm just making an exception today because the wheather is so nice.

Comment: sorry  not working getting error..I am not able to attach screenshot image. i think the  Invoke-Expression command not excuting

Comment: I am using power-shell to execute in loop and get the details and append prefix to each line

Comment: i need to execute this command echo $g; Invoke-Expression "$(Get-vm -name $g*|get-datastore|select-object *|grep DatastoreBrowserPath)" >> "c:\test"

Comment: @BelvendranRanjan *"get the details and append prefix to each line"* That is not what your bash code is doing. Please edit your question and show samples of desired and actual output, and also the error you're getting.

Comment: in bash i can't run vmware powercli. But i need the same function using for loop

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the weather is indeed nice! You're too good for this world ;)

Comment: foreach ($g in cat 'C:\path\to\input.txt') {
    echo $g; Invoke-Expression "$(Get-vm -name $g*|get-datastore|select-object *|grep DatastoreBrowserPath)" > 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
}

Comment: PLEASE. EDIT. YOUR. QUESTION.